# Laravel eloquent: renaming columns names using "colllection" in query with several relationships

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

**The scenario:**

I need to pull data from table Properties that has relationship with city, neighborhood and category, passing all result through a collection that will "beautify" ugly columns to nice names.

So I do a select using method WITH:

```php
//Query example
$result = Property::query();
$result = $result()->select('somefields')
->with('city')
->with('neighborhood')
->with('category')
->paginate($limit);

//Lets get results and use collection to rename ugly columns name:
PropertyResource::collection($result);
```

//It will rename fields based on this solution: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-toarray

**What's my question:**
PropertyResource only rename columns retrieved from table "Property". Tables "city","category" and "neighborhood" keep the native columns name.

How can I pass $result through other collections?

Comment: Please post `PropertyResource`. What exactly is your expected result?

Comment: Hi, I'll update my answer. The problem is: results that come from other tables are not changed by collection even if I set them in collection.

Comment: You might want to clarify a bit more, add some more code - it is hard to understand what you are doing, and what is your question.

Comment: Serious? Ok, I'll edit entire question.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'v updated the question.

Comment: Serious. Maybe it is a terminology issue, I still don't understand what you are asking. Eg "pass $result through other collections" does not make sense in Laravel.  Your `$result` **is** a collection.  You don't pass things "through a collection", though you can call [collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) on your collections to modify them.  Are you looking for [`$result->transform()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-transform)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In collection method I can rename entire result this way:

```
 <?php

    namespace App\Http\Resources\v1;

    use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

    class Property extends Resource
    {
        /**
         * Transform the resource into an array.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
         * @return array
         */
        public function toArray($request)
        {
            return [
                'id'                    => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'featured'              => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'superFeatured'         => $this->SOMEFIELD,
//THIS ONE COMES FROM A RELATIONSHIP
                'description'           => $this->propertyAdvertisement->SOMEFIELD,
                'saleValue'             => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'saleFormOfPayment'     => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'vacationRentValue'     => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'annualRentValue'       => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'dormitories'           => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'suites'                => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'wc'                    => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'parkingSpaces'         => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'coverImage'            => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'coverDescription'      => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'coverOrder'            => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'features'              => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'category'              => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'subcategory'           => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'city'                  => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'condominium'           => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'neighborhood'          => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'ref'                   => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'privateArea'           => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'totalArea'             => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'terrainSize'           => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'finances'              => $this->SOMEFIELD,
                'ownerParcels'          => $this->SOMEFIELD
            ];
        }
    }
```

This way only one collection can rename the entire result.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir thank you. Stack told me to wait 2 days before check as accepted and I forgot.